# React Container - access state from either reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this. Basically , i have a component which pulls a isFetching boolean from the state

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  const {errorMessage,isFetching} = state.signUp
  const {isAuthenticated,username} = state.login;
  return {
    isAuthenticated,
    errorMessage,
    isFetching,
    username
  }
}
```

i have the below reducers

```
export const signUp = (state={},action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case SIGNUP_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({},state,{
        isFetching: true
      })
    case SIGNUP_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({},state,{
        isFetching:false,
        // isAuthenticated: false,
        errorMessage: action.message
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const login = (state={isAuthenticated:false},action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({},state,{
        isFetching: true,
        isAuthenticated: false
      })
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({},state,{
        isFetching:false,
        isAuthenticated:true,
        username: action.username
      })
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({},state,{
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        errorMessage: action.message
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

when i dispatch a loginRequest - the reducer turns isFetching to true. but the component still doesnt update because its looking at the isFetching variable only from the signUp Reducer.

is there a way i can have the component look at both reducers for the isFetching variable?

Comment: Assuming you used combineReducers, the `state` that your `mapStateToProps` is called with is the combined state, so yes, your component can easily look at the state of `isLoading` in both reducers.

Comment: wouldnt that mean that the state has two isFetching values?  one for signup and on for login? i would like to know if i can have a global isFetching variable that returns true when either signUp request or loginRequest are dispatched

Comment: `state` will have two object, `signUp` and `login`, which both will have `isFetching` boolean. If you want to avoid this, I would just keep all in single reducer, and probably call the new reducer as `authentication`. Alternatively, you can have a simple logic at `mapStateToProps` such as `const isFetching = signUp.isFetching || login.isFetching` and pass it down.

Comment: If you read in the redux github issues, there's some topics about sharing portions of the state between reducers.  The solution is basically to write your own `combineReducers`. Then you can pass both portions of the state to each one. Hope it makes sense. Alternatively, you could setup your `mapStateToProps` to look at both values and return true to your component if either `isLoading` is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple options:

---

**Create a 3rd (loading state) reducer**

Create another reducer which only has the `isFetching` in it's state, and listen for the same events.

```
export const loading = (state={}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SIGNUP_REQUEST:
    case LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({},state,{
        isFetching: true
      })
    case SIGNUP_SUCCESS:
    case SIGNUP_FAILURE:
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({},state,{
        isFetching: false
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

If there is any chance these two requests could overlap, then you should probably have the independent `isLoading` variables and just use `||`.

---

**Check both `isFetching` variables in the view**

```
{signup.isFetching || login.isFetching}
```

This is good if the requests could overlap.

---

**Put it all in one reducer**

not so good..

Comment: went with {signup.isFetching || login.isFetching}